# WCF - Inbound polymorphic array (a property of a datacontract) not getting properly deserialized

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

Here is a simplification of the issue.

I have DataContracts of Type Bar, Bar1, and Bar2.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(Bar1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Bar2))]
public class Bar
{
    Public int SomeVal{get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Bar1: Bar
{
     Public int SomeOtherVal{get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Bar2: Bar
{
     Public int YetAnotherOtherVal{get;set;}
}
```

I have a second DataContract of Type Foo, which has a public property, List.
e.g.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    Public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}

}
```

I have a ServiceContract (Interface) that has 2 methods that support both SOAP and JSON.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooWorld
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat =    WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar1))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar2))]
    Foo GetFoo();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat =  WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar1))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar2))]
    void SetFoo(Foo foo);
}
```

Using SOAPUI, I can confirm that GetFoo is returning the polymorphic array of Bars with a mix of Bar1 and Bar2 objects in the array.

Using logging, I have learned that when I call SetFoo with mixed array of Bar1 and Bar2 objects in the Foo.Bar, Bar itself is not null, but it is empty.

I have the Bar parameter in SOAP in a variety of styles

Style 1 - this caused the inbound Bar array to be allocated but empty

```
<ns:Bars>
    <ns:Bar1>...
    </ns:Bar1>
    <ns:Bar2>...
    </ns:Bar2>
</ns:Bars>
```

Style 2 - this caused the inbound Bar array to have items of type Bar, not Bar1 and Bar2

```
<ns:Bars>
    <ns:Bar i:type="Bar1">...
    </ns:Bar>
    <ns:Bar i:type="Bar2">...
    </ns:Bar>
</ns:Bars>
```

Neither of these are working. Any suggestions on how to support polymorphism of this sort in a DataContract for inbound calls in SOAP and in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `[DataMember]` on each of the properties on your data classes. DataContractSerialiser is an opt in serialiser, meaning you need to opt in for it to do anything with the property.

Change your classes thusly.

```
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    [KnownType(typeof(Bar1))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Bar2))]
    public class Bar
    {
        [DataMember]
        Public int SomeVal{get;set;}
    }

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class Bar1: Bar
    {
        [DataMember]
        Public int SomeOtherVal{get;set;}
    }

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class Bar2: Bar
    {
        [DataMember]
        Public int YetAnotherOtherVal{get;set;}
    }


    I have a second DataContract of Type Foo, which has a public property, List<Bar>.
    e.g.
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class Foo
    {
        [DataMember]
        Public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}

    }
```